# What caused the H3 rocket to squeal so loudly after its launch abort?

Tags: rockets, launch, abort, jaxa

Immediately after the [H3 rocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H3_(rocket))'s first launch attempt [was aborted](https://spaceflightnow.com/2023/02/17/first-launch-of-japans-h3-rocket-aborted-moments-before-liftoff/), a loud squealing noise could be heard on the live stream. What was this?

The only thing I could find about it when searching the Internet was a [Twitter comment](https://twitter.com/NASASpaceflight/status/1626396033507811340?cxt=HHwWmICzleqkj5ItAAAA) by Chris Bergin suggesting that it was expected in some way.

Comment: yikes - somebody set a phaser to overload?

Comment: The tweet makes no sense, considering the rocket has never been launched.

Comment: If you listen through the roar of the engines of the first launch, you can hear the squeal, which suggests it's some pad infrastructure